# Cakephp Email format validation before submit the form

Tags: forms, validation, email, cakephp

I need to validate the Email format before submitting the form in Cakephp.

I was provided an invalid email (i.e. **testuser1** instead of **testuser1@domain.com**). The request was submitted, then got error. If email is invalid, request should not be submitted.

Very curious about what I missed in my code and also referred related questions in forum but that was not work for me. H

Code is:

```
//for email input
 <div class="form-group">
    <?= $this->Form->label("email", __('Email')); ?>
            <?=     $this->Form->text("email", [
                    'required' => true,
                    'label'    => false,
                    'id'       => "email",]);
            ?>
 </div> 


<div class="btn-group btn-group-spaced form-group" role="group" aria-label="Actions">
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'), ['class' => 'btn orange btn-default']) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Clear'), ['class' => 'btn orange hollow btn-default ucase','id' => 'show-prof','type' => 'reset']) ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
//for email input
 <div class="form-group">
    <?= $this->Form->label("email", __('Email')); ?>
            <?=     $this->Form->input("email", [
                    'required' => true,
                    'label'    => false,
                    'id'       => "email",
                    'type'     => "email"
                    ]);
            ?>
 </div> 


<div class="btn-group btn-group-spaced form-group" role="group" aria-label="Actions">
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Submit'), ['class' => 'btn orange btn-default']) ?>
    <?= $this->Form->button(__('Clear'), ['class' => 'btn orange hollow btn-default ucase','id' => 'show-prof','type' => 'reset']) ?>
</div>
```

The `'type' => "email"` will add a `type` attribute with the value `email` to the input.

Read: [CakePHP Form helper](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#options).

Also, you can visit http://www.formvalidator.net/ for more validations

Comment: Please try to avoid code-only answers, especially beginners will have a hard time figuring things out by comparing code. A short hint about the added `type` option and what it does would make this answers much better.

Answer (score 1):

I am answering for my own question.

One small change needs to be done.

That is, instead of **Form->text** use **Form->email** to validate the email before submitting the form.

Code is like:

```
 <?=     $this->Form->email("email", [
                'required' => true,
                'label'    => false,
                'id'       => "email",]);
  ?>
```